# Create a new column as a count of the Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a Pandas DataFrame. How do I create a new column that is like a count of the Pandas DataFrame because I already made my index a Datatime.

For example, the following code is reproducible on your local PC:

```
import datetime
import numpy

dates = [
    datetime.date(2019, 1, 13),
    datetime.date(2020, 5, 11),
    datetime.date(2018, 7, 24),
    datetime.date(2019, 3, 23),
    datetime.date(2020, 2, 16)
]

data = {
    "a": [13.3,12.3,np.nan,10.3,np.nan],
    "b": [1,0,0,1,1],
    "c": ["no","yes","no","","yes"]
}

pd.DataFrame(index=dates,data=data)
```

Right now, I would like to add a new column as a count. Something like 1,2,3,4,5 until the end of the data

Comment: `df['count'] = range(1, df.shape[0]+1)`?

Comment: Perfekt! This works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
df['count'] = range(1, len(df) + 1)
```

`len(df)` returns the number of rows in the DataFrame, so you can call the builtin `range` function to create a range from `1` to the number of rows in the DataFrame, and then assign it to a new column. When assigning a range to a column, it is automatically converted to a pandas Series.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a Series using `df.index` and apply some processing to it before assigning it to a column of the dataframe.

Here, we could use:

```
df['count'] = pd.Series(1, index=df.index()).cumsum()
```

Here it would be far less efficient (more than 1 magnitude order) than `df['count'] = np.arange(1, 1 + len(df))` that directly builds a numpy array with the expected values, but it can be useful in more complex uses cases.